# Mulitple users submitting files xls files through google forms. Convert to sheets, consolidate and manage responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google form which accepts spreadsheets with data captured from a survey. I need to consolidate all of the data into a single sheet so that it can be parsed and managed.

The data is submitted as xls. I have code written to convert the xls and pull the relevant data into a single sheet.

However the same users will be uploading the forms multiple times. Each time the old data will be included in the responses. How can I avoid having a huge amount of duplicate responses in my consolidated sheet?

As there will be circa 20 people uploading forms I am at a loss as to how to manage this.

Current code which pulls the last 9 columns from each sheet which is what I am interested in.

```
function myFunction() {
  //Folderid
  

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID");
  var filesToConvert = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID").getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);
    while (filesToConvert.hasNext()){ Drive.Files.copy({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{id: "FolderID"}]}, filesToConvert.next().getId());}
  
  var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var filetype;
  var ssID;
  var combinedData = [];
  var data;



  while(filesIterator.hasNext()){
    file = filesIterator.next();
    filetype = file.getMimeType();
   if (filetype === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
      ssID = file.getId();
      data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID)
      combinedData = combinedData.concat(data);
    }//if ends here
  }//while ends here

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Combined");
  ws.getRange("A2:J").clearContent();
  ws.getRange(2, 1, combinedData.length, combinedData[0].length).setValues(combinedData);
}




function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var ws = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = ws.getRange(4, ws.getLastColumn()-9, ws.getLastRow(), 10).getValues();


return data;

}
```

Comment: do you have a unique identity column in the spreadsheets?.(id?timestamp?) I assume you mean you have 20 users with 20 different sheets which will be uploaded multiple times.

Comment: There's a series of dates that'd be unique in column A but each subsequent sheet that each of the 20 would update would include it + a couple of new dates

Comment: This is a question that probably requires a knowledge of application specific information which you have not provided.

Comment: I don't think so as each file is submitted the form names them after the submitter xxxxx - name I think.